# Get rows from multiple sheets from google spreadsheet php api

Tags: php, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I have a file with multiple sheets on google drive.
When i tried to run this code:

```
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($google_file, $range);
```

The result i get are only the rows from the first sheet.
I can see the name s of the sheets by this code:

```
foreach($response->getSheets() as $s) {
                $sheet_name = $s['properties']['title'];
            }
```

But, how can i get the rows of all each one of them please?
Thanks!

Comment: why not just do $s['properties']['title']?  why are you calling anything.

Comment: Because i dont want the names, i want the all rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
$rows = array();
            foreach($response->getSheets() as $s) {
                $sheet_name = $s['properties']['title'];
                $range = "'".$sheet_name."'!A1:BL";
                $rows[$sheet_name] = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($google_file, $range)->getValues();
            }
```